# How to make mirror of remote folder with ftp in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, cron

I have a ftp location and I need to write shell script to mirror it in a specific interval. I will set the timer with Linux cron but how can I use ftp to mirror the remote folder with my local folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this.....

`#!/bin/bash`

`HOST='172.13.17.11'`

`USER='username'`

`PASS='password'`

`TARGETFOLDER='/mnt/htdocs/businessfiles/files'`

`SOURCEFOLDER='/somefolder'`

`lftp -f "`

`open $HOST`

`user $USER $PASS`

`lcd $TARGETFOLDER`

`mirror --verbose $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER`

`bye`
"`